# React + Vite page is not showing anything

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vite

I am pretty new to web dev and I am currently trying to build something with React + Vite.
But when I run `npm run dev` the page shows me a completely white screen like this:[image: the page I am writing]

And there is no error in the terminal: [image: terminal output]

I have no idea where to look
But this is my App.jsx: [image: App.jsx]
This is my Navbar.jsx: [image: Navbar.jsx]

Comment: Check the browser console if any error is there

Comment: Please post code as text, not screenshots

Comment: @Sunlight yeah I found the error in the browser console thank you.

Comment: @Sunlight Yeah, there was an error on my console. After fixing it, the screens were rendering correctly.

Comment: I faced something very similar to this...
The best option here is to check the Chrome console for errors. I found a few there and fixing them promptly rendered the app

Comment: @karthikeyan, you comment very helped me. Thanks, man!

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are using the import directives below:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

Answer (score 1):

In My case i follow example : **[Example Twin + Vite + Emotion + TypeScript](https://github.com/ben-rogerson/twin.examples/tree/master/vite-emotion-typescript)**

Result is same as you. Nothing show. Code not running and error said **"Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined"**

I fix this with replace " <> " with " <React.Fragment> "

```
import React , { Fragment } from "react"
              //  ^^^^^^ can use instead of React.Fragment
function App () {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
     <div> Hello World </div>
    </Reat.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Anyway this is **not correct** way to solve this problem.
Still wating for another answer.

Answer (score 0):

properly wrap the provider around the app component.it is also the reason for blank page

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.jsx'
import './index.css'
import store from './store.js'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

Comment: You're giving advice about the `Provider` for `redux`, but the question never mentions `redux`, so your example doesn't seem relevant